# Should I include academic information not (directly?) relevant to my skill set in LinkedIn

Tags: linkedin

Just some background: I have completed a degree in mathematics and another in computer engineering last year. I am working now as a firmware software engineer in a telecomunications company.

Now the question: I played violin for eleven years in the music conservatory getting two ''degrees'' (not the right word, but i do not know the equivalent) : the elementary one (first 4 years) and the professional one (6 years).

Clearly this is not directly related with my work as a computer engineer. But maybe some recruiters find it interesting (because of creativity, discipline, ability to go pass secondary school and music conservatory, or whatever).

I have just started to use LinkedIn, so I don't really know wether I should include this information.

Should I include this information in my LinkedIn? Or will it just be weird? If I should include it, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, you can add this to your LinkedIn profile. There is a section for "Interests" that works just fine for this purpose. Given your years of formal study, it would be prudent to also include the conservatory in the "Education" section of your profile.

If you like, you can include a few of your most significant musical proficiencies in the "Skills & Endorsements" section. All of this gives a picture of you as an individual, and is totally appropriate for LinkedIn—though you would likely cut much of it from a one-page resume for a job not related to music.

I attended a music school for several years as well after high school. Though I didn't earn a degree at that institution, and later earned an engineering degree elsewhere, I *do* have an official transcript of my coursework at the former institution. Employers who want a complete history of my post-secondary education get the music school transcript as well as the transcripts related to my Bachelor's degree, as a matter of course, and I list it along with my alma mater on my resume. This has never been "weird" to employers; actually, they like to talk about it during interviews. It's an experience many other candidates don't have, so it makes for good small talk and ice breaker questions.

There is also always a possibility of finding a tech opening with an employer whose business is related to music in a way that makes your experience important, or at least a good fit for the company culture. A recruiter could view your profile who knows of an engineering opening with a company that makes [DAW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_audio_workstation) products, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely I would include it. If you look at your 'Edit Profile' page, there is a section called 'Add A Section'. Under this, I would put them under the 'Honors and Awards' section if there are specific awards you obtained. There is also an 'Interests' section where you could put something about your love of music.
[image]